# How to stop particles crossing the solid cylinder boundary?

Tags: matlab, indexing, simulation, particles, random-walk

I am doing a random walk particle tracking simulation. In my problem, I have to implement a reflected boundary on the cylinder. In this code, the check implies that if particles enter into the cylinder, their previous position should not change. I mean, if a particle crosses the solid boundary, such a move is rejected, and the tracer stays at its previous position during the current iteration.  For clarification, I have attached an image where you can see particle sitting in the circle.
[image: particle sitting in the circle]
However, particles still entering into the cylinder. Below is my code.

```
%% loop starts

for i = 1:T            %  T is the total computation time of  simulation
  t = i*dt;               %  dt is the  time step
  %% Particle tracking starts
    
  x_ out = x_previous + u.dt + sqrt(2Ddt);  % x_out--> current position
                                            % x_previous--> previous position
                                            % u -> x-velocity component 
  y_ out = y_previous + v.dt + sqrt(2Ddt);  % y_out--> current position
                                            % y_previous--> previous position
                                            % v -> y-velocity component
    
  %% Check whether particle is inside the cylinder obstacle 
  % x_c and y_c is the center location for cylinder (obstacle) in the flow
  Incircle = sqrt((x_out - x_c).^2 + (y_out - y_c).^2);  
  Particle_enter  = find (Incircle < D/2);    % Particle entered in obstacle 
                                              % having diameter (D)
  %% if particle cross cylinder boundary, do not update its position
  if ismember(Particle_enter,1) 
    kk1 = find(ismember(isIncircle, 1) == 1);
    x_out(kk1) = x_previous(kk1);             % Do not update location
    y_out(kk1) = y_previous(kk1);
  end        
    x_previous = x_out;
    y_previous = y_out;

end
```

Any modification/correction will be helpful
Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest using cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Could you be please more specific? It would be better if you could provide modifications to the code.

Comment: instead of x y z, use x r phi -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system

Answer (score 0):

Due to rounding error, when comparing `float` or `double`, use

```matlab
a-b > tol  % tol = some error tolerance, say, 1e-10
```

instead of

```
a > b
```

Also, `sqrt` can introduce some numerical error, comparing the squared distance is more accurate.

Try to change these lines in your code into

```matlab
Incircle = (x_out - x_c).^2 + (y_out - y_c).^2;  
Particle_enter  = find (abs(Incircle - D^2/4) < tol);
```

If you randomly generate the initial positions of the particles, make sure they are not inside the obstacle in the first place.

Finally, if a particle hits a **reflected** boundary, shouldn't it be reflected, instead of returning to where it was?

Comment: Hi, there are various methods to implement the no-flux boundary conditions. Reflection of the tracer as you suggested is one of them. Could you explain in my code how to implement this condtion?

Comment: First calculate the collision point. Then reverse the velocity perpendicular to the surface of the obstacle at the collision point, which involves calculation of unit normal vector of the surface. But before you add any new things and, while doing so, unfortunately yet very likely, also introduce new problems into your code, it is better to focus on current crossing obstacle problem.